# JavaScript to check if PHP session exists

Tags: javascript, php, session, if-statement

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    session_start();
    if (!$_SESSION['kool']) {
      alert("session")
    } else {
      alert('work')
      location.href = 'lol.html';
    }

  });
</script>
```

it doesn't work  why ?

Comment: Javascript is not PHP ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a mix of JavaScript and PHP:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    <?php session_start(); ?>//Remove session_start
    if (!<?php echo isset($_SESSION['kool'])?'true':'false'; ?>) {
      alert("session")
    } else {
      alert('work')
      location.href = 'lol.html';
    }

  });
</script>
```

PHP *pre-proccesses* HTML meaning it runs before anything else. PHP will replace anything in `<?php ?>` with what it `prints`.

I'm using `isset` because you need that to check if a variables exists/is defined.

Comment: i have tried the top 2 suggestions and neither works :(

Comment: You started `session` after `character  echo`  it's not TRUE.

Comment: i have php file that creates the session and another php file that shows that the session was created however i cant check if that session exist

Comment: @Devin You can use vihan1086's method, but you have to remove session_start() from its code and place it in the first row of your file. You can not start a session after printing headers and body in stdout with a standard PHP configuration. Sessions have to be started before sending headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the variable **contain** like this:

```
if (!<?php echo $_SESSION['kool']; ?>) {
  alert("session")
} else {
  alert('work')
  location.href = 'lol.html';
}
```

Comment: i have tried the top 2 suggestions and neither works :(

Comment: Can help me more??? What is the error?